# Lock Gsettings Schemas for Only Members of a Certain Group

Tags: 16.04, permissions, lock, gsettings, groups

Does anyone have any idea on a way to lock Gsettings Schemas, so that they can't be overwritten, but **only lock them for members of a certain group**, so that members of said group can't overwrite the setting, while users that are not part of that group can overwrite the setting?

I tried looking everywhere, but to no avail (the best I could find is just a method for locking it for all users), so if anyone knows of a method to do this, it'd be quite helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to figure it out, though, the way I've used to solve this problem can look a bit complicated at first.

1. Firstly, you have to go to /etc/dconf/profile as Root, and copy user to whatever you want the DCONF Profile (works like groups) to be called (e.g: student), and then edit the inside of it, to make sure the system-db setting is that same name as the file. From here on, any places in the answer that say FILENAME are to be replaced with that file's name
2. Then, you simply have to make sure all the locks you wanted are in place at /etc/dconf/db/FILENAME.d/locks, and run a `sudo dconf update` in Terminal
3. Now, for every Home Account of who you want to restrict, you'll have to go into their .profile file (CTRL+H to show hidden files), and write into it `export DCONF_PROFILE="FILENAME"`

Source: https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2015/01/30/locking-down-a-gnome-setting/ (use this if my steps are hard to follow)